How can I execute a function if a user cancels a download in browser during the operation in JavaScript?
I'm using the following JavaScript function to initiate a file download:
function save(object, mime, name) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(object);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = name;
  a.click();
}

This function creates a download link and simulates a click to start the download process. However, I want to run a specific function if the user cancels the download or closes the tab during this operation.

Is there a way to detect if the download is canceled or interrupted so that I can execute a function or handle the situation appropriately? If not, is there a workaround to achieve this?
I understand that JavaScript in the browser has limited access to the download status after the user initiates it, but any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

No, you can't tell - there is no secret workaround

you can consider using window.onbeforeunload to handle cases where the user closes the tab during a download. You can't tell whether the user cancels the download directly tho

You might be able to do something server-side, but certainly not from [tag:javascript]

@fdomn-m Is creating a channel request, right?
